# Is it possible to automate the Compare Presentations feature of PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint, office-automation, powerpoint-2010

Is it possible, either through VBA or interop / VSTO, to automate the "compare presentations" feature of PowerPoint 2010? Simply invoking it would be a start, though ideally I'd like a bit more control - and in the perfect world be able to programmatically retrieve the results.

PowerPoint 2010 lacks the macro recorder, and thus it's not possible to use the old trick of recording a macro, executing the operation manually, and then looking at the generated code. PowerPoint 2007 has the macro recorder, but doesn't support the compare presentations feature.

I think the answer to this question is probably "no", but I'd be delighted to be proved wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To invoke it:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ReviewCompareAndMerge")
```

You can find the name of other commands to use like this by going to the ribbon customize dialog box, finding the command you're after, then hovering the cursor over it.  The tool tip that appears will show you the magic bit of text to use (it's the last part, in parentheses).

Ah. Or:

```
ActivePresentation.Merge "c:\temp\test.pptx"
```